# Is there any more smart way of putting my app on the top whenever user is trying to switch into another app. Please check my code in onPause()

Tags: android

Is there any more smart way of putting my app on the top whenever user is trying to switch into another app. Please check my code in onPause().

```
public class temp_activity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_activity);

}


@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    Intent intent = new Intent(temp_activity.this, temp_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: Back-stack is maintained by OS and is in order the applications has been opened by user. It will be LIFO pattern i.e. Last opened application will be on top of the stack.

Comment: may be i took you wrong. my intention is to put my app on focus (foreground) whenever my app has been put on background